# can I change 'Always use custom logon background' value to enable in a bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to change 'Always use custom logon background' value to enable in a bat file.

Is it possible? I can change it manually.

I want to set the **value** to `Enabled`

You can see it below.

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I think you would need GPMC https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21895 to run from command line.

Comment: Sure use `Reg /?`. Windows will reset it every two hours. You need to be an admin to do this.

Comment: Yes I am admin, I wrote in my question I can do it manually

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could you edit a specific group policy using a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580671/how-could-you-edit-a-specific-group-policy-using-a-batch-file)